# 500 Internal Server Error, ImportError: cannot import name app

Tags: apache, flask, windows-server-2012

i am experiencing a 500 Internal Server Error with what is likely the most basic Flask web application ever.  after trying many suggestions to the same problem on similar configurations, i remain unsure what the root of the issue is.

i have the Flask (0.10.1) application **test.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():

    name = request.args.get('name','')
    return 'Hello ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

with the web server gateway interface (mod_wsgi 4.4.13) file **test.wsgi**:

```
import sys

#Expand Python classes path with your app's path
sys.path.insert(0, "C:\project")

from test import app

#Put logging code (and imports) here ...

#Initialize WSGI app object
application = app
```

an Apache (2.4.16) configuration file **httpd.conf**:

```
<Directory C:/project>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias /flasktest
C:/project/test.wsgi
```

which produces the **error.log**:

```
[Mon Aug 17 10:51:17.756781 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 3408:tid 1060] [client 172.20.2.24:61074] mod_wsgi (pid=3408): Target WSGI script 'C:/project/test.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Aug 17 10:51:17.756781 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 3408:tid 1060] [client 172.20.2.24:61074] mod_wsgi (pid=3408): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/project/test.wsgi'.
[Mon Aug 17 10:51:17.756781 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 3408:tid 1060] [client 172.20.2.24:61074] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Aug 17 10:51:17.756781 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 3408:tid 1060] [client 172.20.2.24:61074]   File "C:/project/test.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Mon Aug 17 10:51:17.756781 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 3408:tid 1060] [client 172.20.2.24:61074]     from test import app
[Mon Aug 17 10:51:17.757783 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 3408:tid 1060] [client 172.20.2.24:61074] ImportError: cannot import name app
```

any help in getting to the root of this issue would be much appreciated.  thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a bad idea to name your own module code file 'test.py' as there is a module in the Python standard library called that. If you don't get the Python module search path correct, it will pick up the one from the Python standard library when you say 'from test import app'. BTW, it is a bad idea to rely on changing the working directory in web applications. Set module search paths correctly and construct absolute path names when accessing files rather than use relative path names.

Answer (score 0):

the call to change directory suggested in [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/99/) Flask snippet on Apache hosting resolved my issue.  much thanks to author Dorianux.